# Use ng-model in href

Tags: angularjs

Angular is new to me. I try to make a link which contains a dynamic `href` attribute.

So far, I read that using `ng-href` instead of `href` was a good practice. But, when I try this :

```
<a target="_blank" data-ng-href="{{myUrl}}">Follow this URL</a>
```

*(I also tried without the curly brackets)*

The href value does not take the value that I put in the controller :

```
function (data) {
  console.log("data : %o", data);
  console.log("url : "+data.url);
  $scope.myUrl =  data.url;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the value of data as shown is the console :

```
data : Object
  requestTokenId: 3405
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=TBqMIpdz[...]"
  __proto__: Object
```

**More background :**

I want to create a "twitter authorization" modal :

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController">

<!-- 
Some HTML elements on which data-binding works.
-->

<div class="modal fade" id="authorizationTwitterModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span
            class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Authorization</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ol>
          <li>Connect to your account</li>
          <li id="liAuthorizationTwitterURL"><a target="_blank" ng-href="{{myUrl}}">Follow this URL</a></li>
          <li>Authorize Ambasdr</li>
          <li>Copy/Paste the authorization code here :</li>
        </ol>
        <p class="text-center">
          <input id="verifier" name="value" type="text">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, when the user wants to authorize twitter, I call my server, which calls twitter then give me the URL that I want to place into the href:

```
$scope.addTwitterAccount = function(brandId) {
  console.log("addTwitterAccount");
  var popup = wait("Authorization");
  //$scope.myUrl =  'http://www.google.fr'; <- This change works!
  $.doPost("/api/request_token/",
    {
      socialMedia: 'TWITTER'
    },
    function (data) {
      console.log("data : %o", data);
      console.log("url : "+data.url);
      $scope.myUrl =  data.url; // <- This change does not work!
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show more of your model? That seems to be a portion of a proper model.

Comment: @NormanSkinner I added the value of `data` as shown in the console.

Comment: the  `ng-href` directive just prevents "content flashing" . try putting the `{{myUrl}}` somewhere else in the HTML, if it doesnt bind with `$scope.myUrl` your problem is likely elsewhere. If so please provide details about controller, HTML and module defintion

Comment: @NormanSkinner I added some background information. I simplified in order to show a clean question but maybe It removed the bug

Comment: Post the whole code from begin to end you can rename critical areas. Try reconstruct your problem jsfiddle.net etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are making a call to an api outside of Angular? In that case you need to "tell" Angular that a change occurred so that Angular can update the views. To do that you can call `scope.$apply()`:

```
function (data) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.twitterUrl =  data.url;
  }); 
}
```

Comment: This does not work but you are not far from reality because if I change the value before the call to `$doPost`, it works. I am looking at the doc of `$scope.apply`

Comment: Hmmm, actually, it works! (I called $scope.apply instead of $scope.$apply). I must admit that I don't understand *why* it works. I take a look at the doc.

Comment: When I call `$.doPost` (which is actually an extension to the jQuery `$.post()`, I must call `$scope.$apply` myself but if I use `$http.post`, it works.

Comment: Since `$http` is an Angular service, it will automatically trigger a digest loop for you. But since you are doing the call using jQuery you need to trigger a digest loop manually, which is basically what `$apply` does.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is going to see the update to the `$scope`, as changing a `$scope` value causes an Angular `$digest` loop.

You can simply set a regular `href` to your model by using curly braces, as such:

```
<a href="{{myUrl}}">Link</a>
```

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/quximuloko/1/edit?html,js,output) -- hover over the URL first, then click the button, after 1 second the URL will update